# How to check if a PHP array has any value set?

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a signup form, I am using PHP and on my processing part I run some code, if a submitted item fails I then add it to an errors array.

Below is a snip of the code, I am at the point where I need to find the best method to determine if I should trigger an error.

So if there is a value set in the error array then I need to redirect and do some other stuff.

I was thinking of using `isset` or else `is_array` but I don't think that is the answer since I set the array using `**$signup_errors = array()**` wouldn't this make the `is_array` be true?

Can anyone suggest a good way to do this?

```
//at the beginning I set the error array
$signup_errors = array();

// I then add items to the error array as needed like this...
$signup_errors['captcha'] = 'Please Enter the Correct Security Code';
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
if ($signup_errors) {
  // there was an error
} else {
  // there wasn't
}
```

How does it work? When converting to boolean, an empty array converts to false. Every other array converts to true. From the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

> ### Converting to boolean
>
> To explicitly convert a value to
> boolean, use the (bool) or (boolean)
> casts. However, in most cases the cast
> is unncecessary, since a value will be
> automatically converted if an
> operator, function or control
> structure requires a boolean argument.
>
> See also Type Juggling.
>
> When converting to boolean, the
> following values are considered FALSE:
>
> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements
> - an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
> - Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).

You could also use [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) as it has similar semantics.

Comment: +1 I don't know why anyone would want to do anything more complicated than this ...

Comment: +1.  Also good to note that **empty()** should be used if you cannot guarantee your variable has already been initialized (as in the case with $_POST data).

Comment: @toomuchphp probably because if you are unfamiliar with Php's type juggling it's not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps [empty()](http://php.net/empty)?

From Docs:

> ### Return Values
>
> Returns FALSE if var has a non-empty
>   and non-zero value.
>
> The following things are considered to
>   be empty:
>
> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Check if...

```
if(count($array) > 0) { ... }
```

...if it is, then at least one key-value pair is set.

Alternatively, check if the array is not empty():

```
if(!empty($array)) { ... }
```

Comment: since [PHP7.2](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/counting_non_countables), using count() will throw an error if called on a non-countable object. so if your $array is null, this approach will not work.

Comment: Another use case where this will not work: if you use an array name for an input field (like `<input type="text" name="myInputField[]">`) for several items, then, when the form is submitted without any inputs, the $_POST will include an array like this: `myInputField = [0 =>"", 1=>"", etc.]`. Using `count()`, will get a count of the nodes, but there won't be any values.  So a mere `count()` may give you false indication that there are values to be processed.

Answer (score 3):

Use array_filter if you already have keys, but want to check for non-boolean evaluated values.

```
<?php
$errors = ['foo' => '', 'bar' => null];
var_dump(array_filter($errors));

$errors = ['foo' => 'Oops', 'bar' => null];
var_dump(array_filter($errors));
```

Output:

```
array(0) {
}
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(4) "Oops"
}
```

Use:

```
<?php
if(array_filter($errors)) {
    // Has errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check on both the minimum and maximum values of the array, in this case you can have a large array filled with keys and empty values and you don't have to iterate through every key-value pair

```
if(!min($array) && !max($array)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The language construct **isset()**, is for testing to see if variables and array elements are set and not NULL. Using **is_array()** would tell you if the argument you supply to it is an array. Thus, I do not think using isset() or is_array() would give you the *correct* and *desired* result that you are seeking.

The code:

```
$signup_errors = array();
```

means that ...

```
is_array($signup_errors);
```

would return true. However, this does not mean that the Boolean language rules of PHP would evaluate....

```
if($signup_errors)
{
     //*Do something if $signup_errors evaluates to true*;
}
```

as *true*, unless some elements are added to it. When you did this,

```
$signup_errors['captcha'] = 'Please Enter the Correct Security Code';
```

you fulfilled the PHP language requirement for the array above to evaluate to *true*.
Now, if for some reason you wanted, or needed, to use isset() on the array elements in the future, you could. But, the conditional statement above is enough for you this case.

Answer (score 0):

I should add an obvious answer here.  If you initialise your error array as an empty array.  And later want to check if it is no longer an empty array:

```
<?php
$errors = [];

if($errors !== [])
{
    // We have errors.
}
```